# How to make softmax work with policy gradient?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to change Karpathy's code so that it works with softmax function so that I can use it for game with more than 2 actions. However, I cannot get it to work. Can someone help point me to the right direction please? Thanks. Below is my attempt.

```
""" Trains an agent with (stochastic) Policy Gradients on Pong. Uses OpenAI Gym. """
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pickle
import gym

# hyperparameters
H = 100 # number of hidden layer neurons
batch_size = 10 # every how many episodes to do a param update?
learning_rate = 1e-4
gamma = 0.9 # discount factor for reward
decay_rate = 0.9 # decay factor for RMSProp leaky sum of grad^2
resume = False # resume from previous checkpoint?
render = False
num_action = 2

# model initialization
D = 6 # input dimensionality: 80x80 grid
if resume:
  model = pickle.load(open('save.p', 'rb'))
else:
  model = {}
  model['W1'] = np.random.randn(H,D) / np.sqrt(D) # "Xavier" initialization
  model['W2'] = np.random.randn(num_action, H) / np.sqrt(H)

grad_buffer = { k : np.zeros_like(v) for k,v in model.iteritems() } # update buffers that add up gradients over a batch
rmsprop_cache = { k : np.zeros_like(v) for k,v in model.iteritems() } # rmsprop memory

def sigmoid(x): 
  return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x)) # sigmoid "squashing" function to interval [0,1]

def softmax(w, t = 1.0):
    e = np.exp(np.array(w) / t)
    dist = e / np.sum(e)
    return dist

def prepro(I):
  """ prepro 210x160x3 uint8 frame into 6400 (80x80) 1D float vector """
  I = I[35:195] # crop
  I = I[::2,::2,0] # downsample by factor of 2
  I[I == 144] = 0 # erase background (background type 1)
  I[I == 109] = 0 # erase background (background type 2)
  I[I != 0] = 1 # everything else (paddles, ball) just set to 1
  return I.astype(np.float).ravel()

def discount_rewards(r):
  """ take 1D float array of rewards and compute discounted reward """
  discounted_r = np.zeros_like(r)
  running_add = 0
  for t in reversed(xrange(0, r.size)):
    if r[t] != 0: running_add = 0 # reset the sum, since this was a game boundary (pong specific!)
    running_add = running_add * gamma + r[t]
    discounted_r[t] = running_add
  return discounted_r

def policy_forward(x):
  h = np.dot(model['W1'], x)
  h[h<0] = 0 # ReLU nonlinearity
  logp = np.dot(model['W2'], h)
  p = softmax(logp)
  return p, h # return probability of taking action 2, and hidden state

def policy_backward(eph, epdlogp):
  """ backward pass. (eph is array of intermediate hidden states) """
  # print eph.shape
  # print epdlogp.shape
  # print model['W2'].shape
  # dW2 = np.dot(eph.T, epdlogp).ravel()
  # dh = np.outer(epdlogp, model['W2'])
  # dh[eph <= 0] = 0 # backpro prelu
  # dW1 = np.dot(dh.T, epx)
  # return {'W1':dW1, 'W2':dW2}
  dW2 = np.dot(eph.T, epdlogp).T
  # print dW2.shape
  dh = np.dot(epdlogp, model['W2'])
  # print dh.shape
  dh[eph <= 0] = 0 # backpro prelu
  dW1 = np.dot(dh.T, epx)
  return {'W1':dW1, 'W2':dW2}




env = gym.make("Acrobot-v1")
observation = env.reset()
prev_x = None # used in computing the difference frame
xs,hs,dlogps,drs = [],[],[],[]
running_reward = None
reward_sum = 0
episode_number = 0
while True:
  if render: env.render()

  # preprocess the observation, set input to network to be difference image
  cur_x = observation
  x = cur_x - prev_x if prev_x is not None else np.zeros(D)
  prev_x = cur_x

  # forward the policy network and sample an action from the returned probability
  aprob, h = policy_forward(x)
  action = np.argmax(aprob)
  if action == 1:
    action = 2
  # action = 2 if np.random.uniform() > aprob[1] else 0
  # print aprob

  # action = 2 if np.random.uniform() < aprob else 3 # roll the dice!

  # record various intermediates (needed later for backprop)
  xs.append(x) # observation
  hs.append(h) # hidden state

  # if action == 0:
  #   y = [1,0,0]
  # elif action == 1:
  #   y = [0,1,0]
  # else:
  #   y = [0,0,1]


  y = [1,0] if action == 0 else [0,1] # a "fake label"

  dlogps.append(aprob-y) # grad that encourages the action that was taken to be taken (see http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#losses if confused)

  # step the environment and get new measurements
  observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
  reward_sum += reward

  drs.append(reward) # record reward (has to be done after we call step() to get reward for previous action)

  if done: # an episode finished
    episode_number += 1

    # stack together all inputs, hidden states, action gradients, and rewards for this episode
    epx = np.vstack(xs)
    eph = np.vstack(hs)
    epdlogp = np.vstack(dlogps)
    epr = np.vstack(drs)
    xs,hs,dlogps,drs = [],[],[],[] # reset array memory

    # compute the discounted reward backwards through time
    discounted_epr = discount_rewards(epr)
    # standardize the rewards to be unit normal (helps control the gradient estimator variance)
    discounted_epr -= np.mean(discounted_epr)
    discounted_epr /= np.std(discounted_epr)

    epdlogp *= discounted_epr # modulate the gradient with advantage (PG magic happens right here.)
    grad = policy_backward(eph, epdlogp)
    for k in model: grad_buffer[k] += grad[k] # accumulate grad over batch

    # perform rmsprop parameter update every batch_size episodes
    if episode_number % batch_size == 0:
      for k,v in model.iteritems():
        g = grad_buffer[k] # gradient
        rmsprop_cache[k] = decay_rate * rmsprop_cache[k] + (1 - decay_rate) * g**2
        model[k] += learning_rate * g / (np.sqrt(rmsprop_cache[k]) + 1e-5)
        grad_buffer[k] = np.zeros_like(v) # reset batch gradient buffer

    # boring book-keeping
    running_reward = reward_sum if running_reward is None else running_reward * 0.99 + reward_sum * 0.01
    print 'resetting env. episode reward total was %f. running mean: %f' % (reward_sum, running_reward)
    if episode_number % 100 == 0: pickle.dump(model, open('save.p', 'wb'))
    reward_sum = 0
    observation = env.reset() # reset env
    prev_x = None
```

When debugging, this code runs into a "nan" issue which I can't figure out how to fix.

Comment: When debugging, this code also runs into "nan" which I have no idea why.

Comment: May I suggest posting this question on the Crossvalidated section? I think there's a higher chance you will get help there http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not clear what is *Karpathy Code* and like where you're stuck. However, as per title of your question you need to apply *softmax function on output of neurons* and *gradient for adjustment of weights*. Now **NaN** is due to computations reaching infinity (*or big number*). Check that you've **normalized inputs**, **scaled neuron output in -1 to 1**.

Comment: @SACn he has normalized inputs with ```discounted_epr -= np.mean(discounted_epr)``` and  ```discounted_epr /= np.std(discounted_epr)```, so im not sure thats the issue. plus, there is only two hidden layers so i dont think it's a case of vanishing/exploding gradients either.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `NaN` problem that you mention in a comment is due to your Softmax function.

Softmax computes the exponential function, `exp(x)` which can easily exceed the range of single or double precision floats for moderate values of x. This would cause `exp` to return `NaN`.

**Solution**

The mathematical form of Softmax is:

```
s[i] = exp(x[i]) / (exp(x[0]) + exp(x[1]) + .. + exp(x[n-1]))
```

We can divide the numerator and denominator of this expression by an arbitrary value, say `exp(a)` without affecting the result.

```
s[i] = (exp(x[i])/exp(a)) / ((exp(x[0]) + exp(x[1]) + .. + exp(x[n-1])/exp(a)))

s[i] = exp(x[i]-a) / (exp(x[0]-a) + exp(x[1]-a) + .. + exp(x[n-1]-a))
```

If we let `a = max(x)` then all exponents will be zero or negative, so no call to exp will return NaN.

I don't use Python or numpy, but I imagine you could define **softmax** something like:

```
def softmax(w):
    a = np.max(w)
    e = np.exp(np.array(w) - a)
    dist = e / np.sum(e)
    return dist
```